# How do I find the Space Complexity of this code?

Tags: python

I've was writing some code in Python to solve the following problem:

"Implement the function fib(n), which returns the n^th number in the Fibonacci sequence,using only O(1) space."

Below is the code I wrote, but I'm unsure how to find its space complexity.

```
def fib(n):
    x=0
    y=1
    z=0
    
    for num in range(0,n):
        
        if (num % 2) == 0:
            z = x
            x = x+y
            print(x)
        
        else:
            y = x
            x = x+z
            print(x)
    
    return x
```

Comment: Look for growing data structures (e.g. lists) and how they change in size with respect to `n`.

Comment: This problem is logically impossible. The nth Fibonacci number itself takes O(n) space - it is approximately phi^n where phi = 1.618... is the golden ratio, so the number of bits required to represent it in binary is approximately `(log_2 phi) * n`.

Answer (score 0):

To find space complexity, you look at any collections / data-structures you've made.

Any primitive values are constant space.

A `range()` is a generator function that can be considered as constant space since it does not need to maintain more state than its current value and a `step`, as compared to a `list(range())`, which allocates memory for all values between `start` and `end`.

Comment: *"Any primitive values are constant space."* Not when the function uses arbitrary precision integers whose size is exponential in `n`.

Comment: @kaya3 Sure, `N` can be defined in any way you want, but for the algorithm given, I think it means in terms of the N'th fibonacci rather than number of total bytes needed to get to that number

Comment: Yes, and the nth Fibonacci number is exponential in n. It's approximately phi^n where phi is the golden ratio.